# Toggle menu but keep space if checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I have following toggle menu by use of jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){ 
    $(".menu").slideToggle(700);
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  background: #1abc9c;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu ul li:hover { background: #16a085; }
 
.left{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> A</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> B</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> C</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> D</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> a</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> b</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> c</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> d</li>
  </ul>
    
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> #</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> +</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> %</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> =</li>
  </ul>

    <br class="clear" />
</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle">toggle</a>
```

A User now opens the menu and clicks a checkbox. If he closes the menu again, the menu should not fully disappear but the clicked checkboxes should be visible.

Edit:
Please see follwing images. Which show the wanted result after one checks a box and closes the menu again.

[image: one box selected]

The green menu now does not fully hide again as a chechbox stays visible.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by *keep the space*, please specify.

Comment: I´ve added screenshots which show what is meant with "keep the space"

Comment: I understand perfectly well and I'm guessing you keep the space from the onset, rather than when selected

Answer (score 0):

This should slide the individual items, if that's what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){ 
    $(".menu input:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent("li").slideToggle(700);
  });
});
```

Comment: unfortunatly I cannot make this working. does the snippet run in the code editor if you press "Run code snippet"? – but thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this may be kind of what you are looking for. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgx760z8/15/) for it. You can probably play around with it to tailor it to your liking more. If this is not right I will try again but should be a good start for you. Here is the js I included to make it work and is definitively not the best way to go about accomplishing your task though.

```
    $( "li" ).each(function() {
           var x = $(this).find( "input" );
            if(x.prop('checked')==true){
                x.closest('li').css("visibility","visible");
            }else{
            x.closest('li').css("visibility","hidden");
            };
    });
```

Comment: Also if you would  like it I don't mind providing you with explanation of what is happening.

Comment: Did this help any? If not what about it would like to see done differently?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. with your solution the height ov the menu is still fully toggled. what should happen is that if you click a checkbox and click the toggle link again, the menu should not fully disappear as for example one checkbox was clicked and now is visible.

Comment: Ahh yes I now see what you are going for thank you for clarification I will work on this later this evening "its 10 am current" when I get home. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry; you have to also move the css display:none rule over to the rule for the **li** elements rather than the whole menu, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){ 
    $(".menu input:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent("li").slideToggle(700);
return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  background: #1abc9c;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
   display: none;
   }

.menu ul li:hover { background: #16a085; }
 
.left{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> A</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> B</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> C</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> D</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> a</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> b</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> c</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> d</li>
  </ul>
    
  <ul class="left">
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> #</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> +</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> %</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /> =</li>
  </ul>

    <br class="clear" />
</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle">toggle</a>
```